# Get property by name to use in Expression

Tags: c#, reflection, runtime

I have a type `Employee` with public properties of `BaseInfo` type, called `Position` and `Department`.

How should I properly write this method?

```
public BaseInfo GetPropertyByName(Employee employee, string propertyName)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typeof(Employee).GetProperty(propertyName)` to get a PropertyInfo object.

To get the value of the property of that specific instance, use:

```
public BaseInfo GetPropertyByName(Employee employee, string propertyName)
{
    var propInfo = typeof(Employee).GetProperty(propertyName);
    return propInfo.GetValue(employee) as BaseInfo;
}
```

However, this will return null if the property you request is of a type other than BaseInfo.

Comment: ended up with `(BaseInfo)propInfo.GetValue(employee, null);`